# What connectors can I use that are relatively small and low cost but rated at 30A?

Tags: connector

I was going to use Molex Microfit connectors, which use a convenient "latch 
& catch" locking system, but they are not rated at the 30A power level I need.

I noticed the Molex "Fit" series has a "Megafit", but that's still only 23A.

What relatively small and not too expensive connectors can you recommend with a 30A rating?

Ideally I'd like something that is considered "high power, high density".

It's a "wire to board" situation - I need a connector for the board and a connector for a cable.

Comment: Number of contacts? Operating voltage?

Comment: Hot connection? hot disconnect? Inductive load?

Comment: How many poles do you need? Can't you just parallel the load over multiple pins (the way it's done with the 6/8-pin "PCI-Express" power connectors on computer PSUs)? Microfit is 8.5 A per pin, so four pins in parallel would be enough.

Answer (score 1):

https://www.digikey.ca/product-detail/en/molex/1720420401/WM17567-ND/4839831
[image]

https://www.digikey.ca/en/product-highlight/m/molex/power-connectors#current-26
Call D-K tech support to help you

Comment: Possibly useful. However, have you priced a crimp tool? Digikey says $650, and that's going to hurt.

Comment: For low volume you can design the cable and order that

Comment: I usually "crimp" with a pair of pliers and solder, but the super sabre series is impossible to do without a crimper... (Just tried yesterday).